# gruntのタスク実行で「Task not found. Use --force to continue」と出る

Tags: node.js, grunt

このモジュールをgruntで実行したいです。
https://github.com/Fkscorpion/grunt-license-report

gruntfile.jsを下記のように書きました。

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-license-report');

    grunt.initConfig({
        "grunt-License-Report": {
            output: {
                path: './report/licenses',
                format: 'html'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['grunt-License-Report']);

};
```

コマンドラインで「grunt」を実行すると
下記のエラーが出ます。

```
Warning: Task "grunt-License-Report" not found. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

解決方法が分かる方がいましたらよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
gruntfile.jsを以下のように書くことで実行できました。

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        "grunt-license-report": {
            output: {
                path: './report/licenses',
                format: 'html'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-license-report');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['grunt-license-report']);

};
```